# Calling ASP.NET Web API 2 from an SPFx webpart

Tags: spfx, authentication, webapi, cors, openid-connect-protocol

I am facing an issue with authenticating my SPFx webpart against an Azure AD backed Web API. What I have done so far is

- Created a ASP.NET WEB API 2 project. Added OWIN and configured CORS
  and OIDC in the pipeline.
- This works perfectly well when I try to
  authenticate via the browser by calling the endpoint.
- But when I try to do this via SPFx I get a CORS error that says “Origin null is not allowed”. This is same one a couple of others got [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2537)

Some Observations:

- When I deploy my application to an Azure app service and turn on the Authentication from the app service, magically things start to work fine. I am unable to figure out what is it that I am missing in my OIDC configuration that is causing this.
- Also, a bit of network trace showed the following

  1. Options request is sent to Web server
  2. Web server responds with 200 OK
  3. This leads to a redirect 302 to location login.microsoftonline.com with my client ID of the application and other parameters in the querystring.
  4. This redirect throws a CORS error because the Origin header is null in this case.

Below is how OWIN is setup.

Startup.cs

```
 public partial class Startup
 {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy()
            {
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };
            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("https://m365x081712.sharepoint.com");

            CorsOptions corsOptions = new CorsOptions()
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider()
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
                }
            };
            app.UseCors(corsOptions);
            ConfigureAuth(app); //Calls within Startup.Auth.cs
            ConfigureWebApi(app);

        }
 }
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                 new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                 {
                     ClientId = "8755bda6-a388-42fc-a8e1-8f2652603334",
                     Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/m365x081712.onmicrosoft.com/",
                     Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                     {
                         RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                         {
                             string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                             context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                             context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                             return Task.FromResult(0);
                         }
                     }
                 });

        }
}
```

The SPFx (react) code that calls the Web API is

```
import { AadHttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
// .. Omitted bunch of unneeded code.

this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
      .getClient('8755bda6-a388-42fc-a8e1-8f2652603334')
      .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
        client
          .get("https://localhost:44386/api/values", AadHttpClient.configurations.v1,{
            credentials:"include", //probably don't need this.
            method:"GET"
          })
          .then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any[]> => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data: any[]): void => {
            console.log(data);
          });
      });
```

Comment: Please use [this my article](https://spblog.net/post/2018/07/30/Call-Azure-AD-secured-API-from-your-SPFx-code-Story-3-Web-app-(or-Azure-Function)-and-SPFx-with-AadHttpClient)

Comment: @SergeiSergeev The article you shared is for core. I am currently working on ASP.NET Web API 2.

Comment: The code for WEB API 2 with OWIN looks very similar, I'm pretty sure you can get the idea from the post

Comment: @SergeiSergeev I haven't been able to get it to work. Curious to know if you've succeeded with it. I see a few github issues too (linked above) about people complaining the same thing as I am facing. One key difference i see is you are using JwtBearerAuth and I am using OpenIDConnect. Could that be the cause?

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2537

Comment: I believe you should use smth like [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/3d3aa98272375cd8a749a1262f056b65184194d6/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs). Setup jwt authentication (without cors first) and test that it works with Postman. Then add cors (for testing add all origins, all headers and all methods) and test with spfx. `SupportsCredentials ` should be false, remove `credentials:"include"` as well